# Android current playing music image

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-music-player

Is there a way to get the image of the current playing music?

I already created a Receiver to get some data about the playing audio.

```
class MusicReceiver : BroadcastReceiver() {

    override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent?) {

        intent?.let {
            val artist = it.getStringExtra("artist")
            val album = it.getStringExtra("album")
            val track = it.getStringExtra("track")
            val playing = it.getBooleanExtra("playing", false)

            Log.e("Music", "$playing")
            Log.e("Music", artist ?: "no artist")
            Log.e("Music", album ?: "no album")
            Log.e("Music", track ?: "no track")
        }

    }

}
```

This works fine and the meta data get's logged as intended.

But how can I retrieve the image of the audio?

As you can see in the [MediaPlaybackService](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Music/+/278aaed1eb37763f7dcb2364523db591014a9210/src/com/android/music/MediaPlaybackService.java#749) on line 749 - 755 the only extras put are

1. id (audio sessionId)
2. artist
3. album
4. track
5. playing

I think that it's maybe possible by using the audio session id but I have no clue how.

Or maybe there is a other way to get it?